# What would be the appropriate way to calculate the probability $aX \leqslant Z \leqslant bY + cX$?

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-distribution

What would be the appropriate way the calculate the probability $aX \leqslant Z \leqslant bY + cX$ where $X,Y,Z$ are all independent exponential variable with parameter ${\lambda _1},{\lambda _2},{\lambda _3}$ and $a,b,c$ are all positive number.

Since $Z$ has been squeeze between $aX$ and $bY + cX$, I guess we could use some the difference between CDF but I cannot wrap my mind around the case where $a>c$ ?

Please help me with this

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$P(t \leq Z \leq s)=e^{-\lambda_3 t}-e^{-\lambda_3 s}.$$ So $$P(aX \leq Z \leq bY+cX)=E(e^{-\lambda_3 aX}-e^{-\lambda_3 (bY+cX)}).$$ This is equal to $$\int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{\infty} (e^{-\lambda_3 ax}-e^{-\lambda_3 (by+cx)}) \lambda_1 e^{-\lambda_1 x} \lambda_2 e^{-\lambda_2 x} dxdy.$$

Comment: If $a>c$ will anything strange happen ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh No. Nothing  goes wrong if $a>c$.

Comment: Rama Does your approach the same as 
$\Pr \left( {aX \leqslant Z \leqslant bY + cX} \right) = \Pr \left( {Z \leqslant bY + cX} \right) - \Pr \left( {Z \leqslant aX} \right)$

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @TuongNguyenMinh